# Maven plugin gwt-maven-plugin error goal compile

Tags: java, maven, gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

I am having trouble building my project. When doing this I'm getting a error on gwt-maven-plugin in version 2.8.0. More infos:

- Apache Maven 3.3.9,
- openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
- Ubuntu 16.10

What might this be causing?

Log:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.0:compile (compile) on project gwt-editor: Command [[
[ERROR] /bin/sh -c '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java' '-Xmx1024M' '-Xss1024k' 'com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler' '-logLevel' 'INFO' '-war' '/home/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.3.0/server/gwt-editor/target/gwt-editor-4.3.0' '-localWorkers' '2' '-draftCompile' '-XfragmentCount' '-1' '-sourceLevel' 'auto' '-style' 'PRETTY' '-gen' '/home/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.3.0/server/gwt-editor/target/.generated' 'org.zanata.webtrans.Application'
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.8.0:compile (compile) on project gwt-editor: Command [[
/bin/sh -c '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java' '-Xmx1024M' '-Xss1024k' 'com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler' '-logLevel' 'INFO' '-war' '/home/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.3.0/server/gwt-editor/target/gwt-editor-4.3.0' '-localWorkers' '2' '-draftCompile' '-XfragmentCount' '-1' '-sourceLevel' 'auto' '-style' 'PRETTY' '-gen' '/home/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.3.0/server/gwt-editor/target/.generated' 'org.zanata.webtrans.Application'
]] failed with status 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at io.takari.maven.builder.smart.SmartBuilderImpl.buildProject(SmartBuilderImpl.java:334)
    at io.takari.maven.builder.smart.SmartBuilderImpl$ProjectBuildTask.run(SmartBuilderImpl.java:104)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command [[
/bin/sh -c '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java' '-Xmx1024M' '-Xss1024k' 'com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler' '-logLevel' 'INFO' '-war' '/home/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.3.0/server/gwt-editor/target/gwt-editor-4.3.0' '-localWorkers' '2' '-draftCompile' '-XfragmentCount' '-1' '-sourceLevel' 'auto' '-style' 'PRETTY' '-gen' '/home/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.3.0/server/gwt-editor/target/.generated' 'org.zanata.webtrans.Application'
]] failed with status 1
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile(CompileMojo.java:520)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute(CompileMojo.java:387)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommandException: Command [[
/bin/sh -c '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java' '-Xmx1024M' '-Xss1024k' 'com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler' '-logLevel' 'INFO' '-war' '/home/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.3.0/server/gwt-editor/target/gwt-editor-4.3.0' '-localWorkers' '2' '-draftCompile' '-XfragmentCount' '-1' '-sourceLevel' 'auto' '-style' 'PRETTY' '-gen' '/home/lob/Downloads/zanata-platform-platform-4.3.0/server/gwt-editor/target/.generated' 'org.zanata.webtrans.Application'
]] failed with status 1
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.JavaCommand.execute(JavaCommand.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile(CompileMojo.java:516)
    ... 14 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :gwt-editor
```

Plugin configuration:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-i18n</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
        <!--here we bind it to generate-test-resource because we want it to happen before the real compile(prepare-package) and able to do its job -->
        <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
        <configuration>
          <module>org.zanata.webtrans.ApplicationI18n</module>
          <extra>${project.build.directory}/gwt-extra</extra>
          <extraParam>true</extraParam>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: These are the most irritating ones... Try with with maven debug enabled? Is it possible run manually this cmd `/bin/sh -c '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java  ...` that is in the exception?

Comment: Can you add the logs from earlier in the build as well? Usually that is where it shows the actual error that made the compiler quit after failure.

Comment: Can you launch said command manually and see what happens? It will probably still return 1 but you may see additional output in the console not shown in the build log